# Convert pdf document into hierarchical JSON format using Python

Tags: python, pdf, nlp, artificial-intelligence, data-extraction

I am trying to detect the headings and sections from pdf documents and assign each paragraph to their parents, like child-parents relation.

For example, if we have :

```
> 2-General Introduction

> 2.1-Definition 

sentence 1

> 2.2.Related works 

sentence 2
```

I want to get an output like this:

```
[{id:'2.1.a',
text:'sentence 1',
parents:[Definition,General Introduction]
},
{id:'2.2.a',
text:'sentence 2',
parents:[Definition,Related works]
}
]
```

Is there any library/tools which helps me getting this output? If not, I am open to building an NLP model but there are any related works or articles to know how and where to start?

Many thanks,

Comment: I am looking for the same question too, do you have any outcome so far (=?